# Class Diagrams: Does Every Use Case Need to Be Drawn With Repeating Classes?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have several use cases I have to represent in a UML class diagram. Apparently repeating classes is not encouraged, and several of my use cases reuse the same classes. I've one particular use case that reuses several classes I have already drawn up, without any unique new classes: does that mean I can leave that particular use case out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Any diagram you create from a UML is an aspect of the whole model. To transport the whole picture you take many pictures from several aspects. Choosing the right number is an art as well as designing the model. A single diagram will in almost all cases not fit. So break them down and create e.g. a single or multiple diagrams per use case (one to highligh requirements, one for the actions, another one for the classes collaborating).

Further it is advisable to create a collaboration that realizes a use cases which holds and separates the realization of the requirements/descriptive part of a use case.

Answer (score 1):

The core difficulty you have stems from an unclear understanding of the UML constructs and their interdependence.

A use case describes an interaction between an actor of the system to achieve a specific purpose. A class is a collection of system data and functions. Of course, different use cases make use of the same classes. Imagine a shop system. The class `Product` describing the products offered by the shop will be used by use cases like `Show all products of a specific category`, `Show product details for a specific product`, `Order product`, `Generate bill for delivered product`.

Fortunately, this repeated use of a class won't clutter your diagrams. In a use case diagram, you don't describe classes, and in a class diagram, you don't describe use cases.

A good approach comes from two directions. Use the input coming from your users to describe use cases: situations when they want to use the application, and the behavior they expect from it. Use your domain knowledge to describe data structures and operations to support these use cases, and describe these in a class model.